# Getting value from input using .value is returning ""

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the value inside the input box and display it on the console

```
<form action="#">
    name : <input type="text" id="name">
</form>
```

```
let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
console.log(name);
```

But it is returning empty in console log. How can I get the value from input box?

Thanks

Comment: When is this code executed?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/codingNewbie/kvw0d9op/3/

Comment: Everything is correct here: you run this code as soon as the page loads; the input contains nothing; nothing is logged; end of story. Familiarize yourself with [DOM events](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Events).

Comment: your jsfiddle does not give the information: when is this JS code  executed ? (actualy it run only on the page load)

Comment: There is no event for Form submit. Learn about events like submit, click etc.

Comment: do you have a submit button in that form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to initiate form submit

```
<form action="#" id="form1">
    name : <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now add event listener for Submit event

```
document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    // Prevent default behavior to avoid page refresh
    e.preventDefault();
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    console.log(name);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keyup` event on input for when you type in input it will display value in console like below example:

```js
const nameInput = document.getElementById('name');

nameInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e)=> {
  console.log(nameInput.value)
});
```

```html
<form action="#">
    name : <input type="text" id="name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a blank value of the input field because you have not added any value attribute in the input field.
So you have to add a value attribute in the input field.

```js
let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
console.log(name);
```

```html
<form action="#">
    name : <input type="text" id="name" value="my custom value">
</form>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is get the value I type in the input box and display it on the console

Comment: @codingNewbie, What Masood said is right, you are using vanilla javascript to get the input value.  Again we can help you if you have a problem, but you need to get familiarized with DOM Events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: @codingNewbie You can use onchange Event for getting the value of the input field.